# Angular - orderBy string as number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, underscore.js

Im using youtube json api and it returns the viewcount as a string, but i need to sort it as an number. How could i do this without going thru the whole model and converting strings to ints?

json snippet

```
yt$hd: Object
yt$statistics: Object
favoriteCount: "0"
viewCount: "1443"
__proto__: Object
```

and im invoiking sorting like

```
orderBy:'yt$statistics.viewCount'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that firmilar with Angular, but I'd assume that `orderBy` parameter can take a function in place of a string like [Lo-Dash does with its `sortBy() function](http://lodash.com/docs#sortBy). In which case you'd probably want something like this:

```
orderBy: function(obj){
  return ~~obj.yt$statistics.viewCount
}
```